# Convert a parent-child-grandchild hierarchy to another p-c-gc hierarchy

Tags: vb.net, linq, list

I have a List of objects A. Each A contains a list of B. Each B contains a list of C.
I would like to know if it is possible to convert it in an elegant way using linq in another list of similar objects D, each of them containing a list of E each of them containing a list of F.
Say, for the sake of the example, that each class has just a numeric ID and a string Description (and of course a list of children in the case of A,B,D,E).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that D, E, and F have constructors that accept ID, description and in the case of D and E, an `IEnumerable` of B and C respectively, you can use this:

```
Dim list As List(Of A)
Dim listSummary As List(Of D) = list.[Select](
    Function(a) New D(a.Id, a.Description, a.Children.[Select](
                      Function(b) New E(b.Id, b.Description, b.Children.[Select](
                                        Function(c) New F(c.Id, c.Description)))))).ToList()
```